# How to copy some values from a file in the repository to the YAML workflow and list them in the input section?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a file `config.json` in my repository that looks like this:

```
{
  "types": {
    "Michael": "M",
    "Dwight": "D",
    "Jim": "J"
  }
}
```

In my GitHub Actions workflow YAML file, I want to list the "types" keys like this:

```
name: The Office

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      cast:
        description: 'The Office Cast'
        required: true
        type: choice
        options:
        - Michael
        - Dwight
        - Jim
```

How do I do this?

I know in the jobs you can use `actions/checkout` and `jq`, but I am not sure if I can use it in the beginning.

Comment: Not supported. You can update the workflow itself when that JSON file changes using `jq`/`yq`.